# Set the input font for comments the same as the display font

Tags: feature-request, comments, fonts

Since the display font for comments is variable width and we can't do formatting that would require a fixed width font for column alignment anyway, is it possible to set the input font to be the same variable width font?

Answer (score 1):

```
| Plead  | action | User    |
|--------|--------|---------|
| Please | don't! | voyager |
```

Writing HTML/code/ASCII art/ASCII tables by hand on a variable width font is `<blink>`***evil***`</blink>`!!!1

```
                             =III.      
                             :III..     
                   .~II=     .?II~.     
                   .~III?.   .~II?.
                    .?III:.  .,III:.
                     .,IIII.  .III+.
             .~.      .=III+. .IIII.    
            .:II=,      :III?. ?III.    
            .=IIIIII=    :IIII,:III,    
              .:IIIIII?.  .IIII.III:    
                .,?IIIIII. ~III.
          ~+,.     ..+IIII7I:.         
         .IIIII?=,.   .~?II:.           
         .IIIIIIIIII?=:
              .:+IIIIIIII?,  
    III            .:+?II=.III          
    III  +II++~~:,.......  III          
    III  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  III        
    III     ~~=+??IIIIIII  III          
    III                    III        
    III  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  III          
    III  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  III          
    III                    III          
    III                    III          
    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII        
    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

Comment: You write ASCII tables into comments?

Comment: That'd be one hell of a comment

Comment: Noooo! Don't use `<blink>`! Didn't you hear? It's finally [official](http://www.zerodayinitiative.com/advisories/ZDI-10-031/) that `<blink>` is evil.

Comment: Sure, you can put all kinds of things in comments, but they're being displayed using a variable width font. I'm just proposing that the input be done in the same font. It's useless to try to do column alignment since we can't put newlines in comments and have to get tricky in order to even try to get things to line up.